# Converting my Swift code to Swift 2.0 Issues

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I am trying to convert my code into Swift 2.0 but I am running into an issue.

Can someone please tell me what this means and how to fix it?

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
>
> ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES)
> cannot be used together clang: error: linker command failed with exit
> code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to project's `Build Setting` panel, search for `BitCode`, and set the value of `Enable Bitcode` to **NO**

[image]

Comment: Yes but won't this disable me from archiving my app to the App Store?

Comment: @TripPhillips [documentation of bitcode in developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2)

Answer (score 1):

Bitcode is the default but optional so you can disable it.

From [Bitcode (iOS, watchOS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2):

> Note: For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode. For watchOS apps, bitcode is required.